# Моделирование отдыха пассажиров

Tags: алгоритм, моделирование

В вычислительной системе моделируется отдых пассажиров на прогулочном катере. Катер вмещает `N` человек и совершает кольцевые прогулки по расписанию через равные промежутки времени. Если к моменту очередного отправления пассажиров нет, катер остается на месте до следующего времени отправления. По окончании прогулки все пассажиры покидают катер. Пассажиры не садятся на катер до выхода прибывших пассажиров. Каждый пассажир моделируется процессом

Процесс i-й пассажир:

```
while (1) {
<зайти на катер>
<сойти с катера>
}
```

Катер представляется процессом:

```
<приплыть из гавани>

while(1){
do {
<ждать время T>
} while(число пассажиров == 0);
<совершить прогулку>
}
```

Опишите схему организации прогулок, используя семафоры Дейкстры и разделяемые переменные.

я правильно понимаю, что нам нужно завести три семафоры, например `empty`, `full` и `mute`. И для пассажира делать что-то типа

```
semaphore empty = N;
semaphore full = 0;
semaphore mute = 1;
```

Passanger

```
while(1) { come_into;
  P(empty);
  P(mute);
  come_out;
  V(mute);
  V(full);
 }
```

не совсем понимаю, как мне вставить катер в процесс для пассажира, чтобы он выходил после прогулки, просто в `while` для катера засунуть `while` для пассажира и операцию `come_out` делать после завершения прогулки?

Comment: Учебное задание небось? Потому что на такой несемантичной штуке как семафоры никто уже полвека не программирует.

Comment: не совсем учебное. Это я пытаюсь разобраться в контрольных заданиях прошлых лет, потому что в грядущей котрольной скорее всего будут подобные задачки на моделирование

Comment: @VladD, разве? Ведь сам Таненбаум пишет, что они используются при внутренней реализации процессов в операционных системах. И я использовал их во FreeRTOS. Так что про полвека вы чересчур резко высказались. Хотя для данной задачи это, наверное, не самый удачный метод.

Comment: @maestro: Во внутренней реализации ОС, там где производительность более важна, чем ясная семантика — пожалуй. Но в прикладных задачах я бы использовал более высокоуровневые примитивы. Хотя да, полвека — это немного, хм, риторическое преувеличение.